# How do I compile a C# solution with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a piece of software that generates code for a C# project based on user actions.  I would like to create a GUI to automatically compile the solution so I don't have to load up Visual Studio just to trigger a recompile.

I've been looking for a chance to play with Roslyn a bit and decided to try and use Roslyn instead of msbuild to do this.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any good resources on using Roslyn in this fashion.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 31):

You can load the solution by using `Roslyn.Services.Workspace.LoadSolution`.  Once you have done so, you need to go through each of the projects in dependency order, get the `Compilation` for the project and call `Emit` on it.

You can get the compilations in dependency order with code like below.  (Yes, I know that having to cast to IHaveWorkspaceServices sucks.  It'll be better in the next public release, I promise).

```
using Roslyn.Services;
using Roslyn.Services.Host;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var solution = Solution.Create(SolutionId.CreateNewId()).AddCSharpProject("Foo", "Foo").Solution;
        var workspaceServices = (IHaveWorkspaceServices)solution;
        var projectDependencyService = workspaceServices.WorkspaceServices.GetService<IProjectDependencyService>();
        var assemblies = new List<Stream>();
        foreach (var projectId in projectDependencyService.GetDependencyGraph(solution).GetTopologicallySortedProjects())
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                solution.GetProject(projectId).GetCompilation().Emit(stream);
                assemblies.Add(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note1: `LoadSolution` still does use msbuild under the covers to parse the .csproj files and determine the files/references/compiler options.

Note2: As Roslyn is not yet language complete, there will likely be projects that don't compile successfully when you attempt this.

Comment: Is there a convenient way of determining the dependency order (like `sln.ProjectsInDependencyOrder`) or is this something I would have to implement on my own? (e.g. Going through project-references and building a dependency tree)

Comment: There is an IProjectDependencyService that has GetTopologicallySortedProjects().  I don't have a computer handy to check exactly how to get it, but will update later.

Comment: This solution doesn't work in the current preview 1.0.0-beta1-20141031-01. `Roslyn.Services.Workspace.LoadSolution()` doesn't exist, neither does `Solution.Create()`. I think you have to use `MSBuildWorkspace.Create` along with `OpenSolutionAsync` (for existing sln) or just `workspace.CurrentSolution` for empty one. As well, you'll need to install the MSBuild 2015 tools from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44931 in order to use an MSBuildWorkspace. Or, you can MEF export a catalog and use `CustomWorkspace`. The whole process has gotten much more complicated it seems

Comment: To add to @JoshE's comment, the Solution class now has a `GetProjectDependencyGraph` method that does all of this, once you have the Solution object.

Answer (score 24):

I also wanted to compile a full solution on the fly. Building from [Kevin Pilch-Bisson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/678625/kevin-pilch-bisson) and [Josh E's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105566/josh-e), I wrote code to compile itself and write it to files.

**Software Used**

Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 1

Microsoft.CodeAnalysis v1.1.0.0 (Installed using Package Manager Console with command `Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis`).

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;

namespace Roslyn.TryItOut
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string solutionUrl = "C:\\Dev\\Roslyn.TryItOut\\Roslyn.TryItOut.sln";
            string outputDir = "C:\\Dev\\Roslyn.TryItOut\\output";

            if (!Directory.Exists(outputDir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDir);
            }

            bool success = CompileSolution(solutionUrl, outputDir);

            if (success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Compilation completed successfully.");
                Console.WriteLine("Output directory:");
                Console.WriteLine(outputDir);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Compilation failed.");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press the any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static bool CompileSolution(string solutionUrl, string outputDir)
        {
            bool success = true;

            MSBuildWorkspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
            Solution solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionUrl).Result;
            ProjectDependencyGraph projectGraph = solution.GetProjectDependencyGraph();
            Dictionary<string, Stream> assemblies = new Dictionary<string, Stream>();

            foreach (ProjectId projectId in projectGraph.GetTopologicallySortedProjects())
            {
                Compilation projectCompilation = solution.GetProject(projectId).GetCompilationAsync().Result;
                if (null != projectCompilation && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(projectCompilation.AssemblyName))
                {
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        EmitResult result = projectCompilation.Emit(stream);
                        if (result.Success)
                        {
                            string fileName = string.Format("{0}.dll", projectCompilation.AssemblyName);

                            using (FileStream file = File.Create(outputDir + '\\' + fileName))
                            {
                                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                                stream.CopyTo(file);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            success = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    success = false;
                }
            }

            return success;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No value for RuntimeMetadataVersion found. No assembly containing System.Object was found nor was a value for RuntimeMetadataVersion specified through options.

Comment: FYI to use this example you will also need to install Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core and Microsoft.Build Packages

Comment: This appears to be a much better answer as the roslyn.services namespace is obsolete.

Comment: The outputting of the result of the compilation to disk can be simplified significantly. Instead of creating a MemoryStream and formatting a file name and creating a FileStream and copying the memory stream to the file stream you can split one statement into two: Project project = solution.GetProject(projectId); Compilation projectCompilation = project.GetCompilationAsync().Result; and then a bit later simply specify projectCompilation.Emit(project.OutputFilePath). (This does assume the .csproj file correctly specifies the output file.)

Comment: As per https://gist.github.com/DustinCampbell/32cd69d04ea1c08a16ae5c4cd21dd3a3, you need to reference the NuGet package `Microsoft.Build.Locator` and call `MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults()`. In my experience, not doing this results in a `Compilation` without any framework references in it.

Comment: Further issues compiling. Need some more nuget dependencies. (see https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/17401)
Microsoft.Build, Microsoft.Build.Framework,Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core