# How to build solution with roslyn with dependencies

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to compile in memory solution using roslyn same way it is described in [How do I compile a C# solution with Roslyn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280008/how-do-i-compile-a-c-sharp-solution-with-roslyn) . The solution I am trying to build referring couple nuget packages and it is ASP.NET WebAPI solution. My problem is that I am getting all sort of reference errors including System.String is unknown. Is there any way to accomplish the task via roslyn? (I know I can use command line tools and then load assemblies, but I would prefer not to do that)

Comment: This should be possible with Roslyn, but it seems like some references are failing to load somehow. Check the diagnostics on the projects that you are trying to compile. Remember that references that are failing to load end up as warning in Visual Studio, and not errors, so you should check all diagnostics.

Comment: Can you share some code that shows how you're trying to compile the code?